# Codeigniter scrollpagination

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, infinite-scroll

I am using jquery plugin **scrollpagination** in codeigniter i am facing problem that my loop does not terminate and alos not giving accurate result.

this is my **html** code

```
<div id="main">
    <div id='friend_display'>
    <?php if($list->num_rows() > 0  ){
            foreach($list->result() as $show)
            {   ?>

    <div class="image-box" style="margin-left:30px" id='image-holder' >

        <div class="photo-cover">
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" class="big-image"><img width="160px" height="117px" src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/friends/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" alt="" /></a>
        </div>

        <p class="photo-name"><b><?php echo $show->user_name;?></b></p>


    </div>
    <?php } } else { echo '<div align="center" style="color:#FF0000; font-size:17px; font-weight:bold">You have no Friends yet</div>';}?>

    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
</div></div>
```

this is **script**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var page_num = 1; 
   $(function(){
$('#friend_display').scrollPagination({
    'contentPage': '<?=base_url()?>friends/load_more', // the url you are fetching the results
    'contentData': {page_num:$('.image-box').size()}, // these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
    'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
    'heightOffset': 10, // it gonna request when scroll is 10 pixels before the page ends
    'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load function, you can display a preloader div
        $('#loading1').fadeIn();    
    },
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){ // after loading content, you can use this function to animate your new elements
         $('#loading1').fadeOut();
         var i = 0;
         $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();
         page_num:$('.image-box').size();
    }
});

// code for fade in element by element
$.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
        delay += 100;
    });
};

 });
</script>
```

and this is my **php** function

```
  function load_more() 
{
    $offset =   $this->input->post('page_num');
    $list       =   $this->friends_model->show_friends($offset);
    if($list->num_rows()>0)
    {
        foreach($list->result() as $show)
        {?>

            <div class="image-box" style="margin-left:30px" id='image-holder'>
            <div class="photo-cover">
            <a href="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" class="big-image"><img width="160px" height="117px" src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/user_images/friends/<?php echo $show->user_image;?>" alt="" /></a>
            </div>

        <p class="photo-name"><b><?php echo $show->user_name;?></b></p>

    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <?php
    } 
    else 
    {  
        //echo(333); 
    }
}
```

in **db** i jst shoing main query
               $this->db->limit(12,$offset);
can someone tell me what i am missing?

Open this Link to wathch complete code.[Scroll Pagination](http://pastebin.com/MC1KZm8y)

Comment: Your question isn't detailed enough. Which loop fails, what're the results of it failing, and most importantly [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: the problem is that when i sroll down it display result and dont stop to display. supose in my db i have 50 result then i first use 10 result to display then when scrollpagination call goes it dispaly jst 10 and so on dispaly jst 10 first not other 40. and loop not ended if i scroll down it continuously display me jst 10 result

Comment: It sounds as if your offset value isn't managed correctly. Make sure the value is passed correctly by `var_dump`ing and changing it till it works.

Comment: problem is offset value, in my js the **page_num** is not returning accurate result of offset

Comment: @Robin Castlin open link and see the full code to understand what i want to say
i  have updated question and added a link

Comment: I dont know if scrollPagination using *GET* or *POST* method to communicate with the server, but you used `$offset =   $this->input->post('page_num');` to get the offset, try use `$this->input->get('page_num')` instead

Comment: scrollPagination.js using POST method, i have also try with get method both way same error. actually i m geeting first time value 12 with $offset = $this->input->post('page_num'); but next time ajax call goes then it also get 12 it should get 24, so it is problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here i solve this problem in my own way you can try this.In your script remove this line

```
'contentData': {page_num:$('.image-box').size()},
```

and add this line

```
 'childClass' : '.image-box',
```

After open scrollpagination.js file then replace this line  `data: opts.contentData,` with this `data: {page_num : $(obj).children(opts.childClass).size()},`. Again replace `'contentData' : {},` this line with `'childClass'  : '.datalist',`.

In your `function display_friends()` please replace `exit;` function with this line `echo '<input type="hidden" id="nodata" value="1" />';` . After that write your script look like this :

```
$(function(){

    $('#nomoreresult').hide();
    $('#loading1').hide();
    $('#friend_display').scrollPagination({

    'contentPage': 'Your_Url', // the url you are fetching the results
     // these are the variables you can pass to the request, for example: children().size() to know which page you are
    'childClass' : '.image-box',
    'scrollTarget': $(window), // who gonna scroll? in this example, the full window
    'heightOffset': 10, // it gonna request when scroll is 10 pixels before the page ends
    'beforeLoad': function(){ // before load function, you can display a preloader div
        $('#loading1').show().fadeIn();
    },
    'afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){
     // after loading content, you can use this function to animate your new elements
        $('#loading1').hide().fadeOut();
        $(elementsLoaded).fadeInWithDelay();

        if($('#nodata').val() == '1'){
            $('#friend_display').stopScrollPagination();
            $('#loading1').hide();
            $('#nomoreresult').show().fadeIn();

        }

    }
});

// code for fade in element by element
$.fn.fadeInWithDelay = function(){
    var delay = 0;
    return this.each(function(){
        $(this).delay(delay).animate({opacity:1}, 200);
        delay += 1000;
    });
};
```

Comment: Nice one solution, it solve 60%. but now problem is by changing scrollpagination.js is that if I scroll fast then it not gets correct page value and may get same value in next scroll down of i scroll fast and the 2nd one problem is that it is endless scroll down. it is not terminating after geeting no more result it should display my 2nd dive as i show in pastebin. and thanks again...

Comment: hi @AyshaAli, i update my answer based on your this topic: "it is not terminating after geeting no more result it should display my 2nd div". I hope this will solve 2nd problem but in 1st problem about same content loading i will see. Thanks

Comment: @AyshaAli i don't know why you get same result but in my test i don't get same result.

Comment: thanks for giving me ur precious time,
but i can't understand that y i am getting sometimes duplicate value, the code is same as yours....then what is problem i dont understand

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26622/discussion-between-syed-ahmed-and-aysha-ali)

Answer (score 2):

I belive that the way you are fetching offset isn't correct. (Thought I'm not sure because I don't know what is in your POST['page_num'])

```
$offset =   $this->input->post('page_num');
```

It looks like you fetch the page number, but the offset in limit function should be how much row has to be skipped. So if you are showing 12 results per "tick" offset should be 12*page_number

```
$this->db->limit(12,$offset*12);
```

If you leave offset to page number, you will get wrong results:

```
limit(12,[0,1,2,...]) // items 1-12, 2-13, 3-14 etc...

limit(12,[0,12,24....] //items 1-12, 13-24, 25-32 etc...
```

Comment: try to do $this->db->limit(6,6*$offset); in your find function

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `jQuery.noConflict()`?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var page_num = 1; 
  jQuery.noConflict();
   $(function(){...
```

Edit2:
It seems your offset works wrong. According to http://pastebin.com/MC1KZm8y

Find:

```
$offset =   $this->input->post('page_num');
$list       =   $this->friends_model->find($offset);
```

Replace:

```
$page_line = 6; //for example
$page_num = $this->input->post('page_num');
$offset   = ($page_num -1) * $page_line;
$list       =   $this->friends_model->find($offset);
```

Comment: its not in controller problem i think its javascript problem or scrollpagination.js problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add this missing code inside the `afterLoad:function(){..` code also this should stop looping your pagination make sure to add exactly same id that you entered for the `scrollpagination id <div id='friend_display'>`

```
if ($('#friend_display').children().size() > 100){ //set the condition to where to stop
// if more than 100 results already loaded, then stop pagination (only for testing)
    $('#nomoreresults').fadeIn(); //if you want to show message like "No more result!" use this
    $('#friend_display').stopScrollPagination();// this is the most important function call
}
```

---

inside `.scrollPagination({..` change `'contentPage': '<?php echo base_url();?>controller/action'` inside this `action(){ $this->load->view('that_you_want_to_display');` it means your display_friends() method only should contain the view file that want to load and parse and the data that you want to display and inside that view echo your data using the foreach

Comment: no it does not mater by changing id, btw i tried this but not successed...thanks for ur ans..

Comment: @AyshaAli yes I checked your code again i found that you have missed the plugin code inside afterLoad': function(elementsLoaded){.. check my answer again

Comment: i was doing this same in `scrollPagination.js` but there was some if condition problem so it is not stoping loop but now fix this problem..thanks
but the previous big problem is still remain that i m geting duplicate values.